# Using decode in where clause, with "in"

Tags: sql, oracle, decode, sql-in

Have a tricky situation in witch I belive you guys can help me out.
I want to use decode in my cursors where-clause. I am using "IN()" but I belive the program thinks the comma belongs to the decode and not as a separator between values.

I think maybe using CASE might solve this, am I right?

```
 CURSOR order_cur (
  cur_ao    VARCHAR2) IS 
  SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
      FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
     WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
           AND t1.ao IN (DECODE (
                            cur_ao,
                            'ALLA', Argus_ehandel_pkg.get_ehorder_ao (
                                       t1.nr),
                            SUBSTR (cur_ao, 1, 2), SUBSTR (cur_ao, 3, 2)))
```

CASE variant

```
CURSOR order_cur (
  cur_ao    VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT t1.nr, t1.status$nr
      FROM eh_order_t@NGEXT_DBLINK t1
     WHERE     t1.status$nr IN (3, 6)
           AND t1.ao IN (CASE
                            WHEN cur_ao = 'ALLA'
                            THEN
                               Argus_ehandel_pkg.get_ehorder_ao (t1.nr)
                            ELSE
                               SUBSTR (cur_ao, 1, 2), SUBSTR (cur_ao, 3, 2)
                         END)                -- SUBSTR (cur_ao, 3, 2) END)
  --AND t1.nr = DECODE (order_in, NULL, t1.nr, order_in)
  ORDER BY t1.skapad_dat ASC;
```

Comment: for sure it does think it belongs to the decode, if you put it inside the decode paranthesis...

Comment: Be careful... it can be very expensive expensive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DECODE** is an expression, and it will work in the **IN** list along with other values in the list, you just need to take care of the **syntax** and **parenthesis**.

What matters is the final value that you get after evaluating the **DECODE** expression. Comma separated values inside DECODE will be evaluated as part of the DECODE expression. And the values after closing the parenthesis of DECODE expression, but inside the **IN list** will be considered in the IN list.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT deptno FROM emp
  2  WHERE deptno IN(decode(ename, 'KING', 20, 10), 30);

    DEPTNO
----------
        30
        30
        30
        30
        10
        30
        30
        10

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

There are two comma separated values in the IN list. DECODE expression is evaluated as `10`, and `20` is in the IN list. So, the IN list is finally evaluated as:

```
WHERE deptno = 10 OR deptno = 20
```

10 is the result of **DECODE**, and 30 is hardcoded in the **IN list**.

---

**Update :**

OP posted a **CASE** expression and the same could written using **DECODE**.

Your CASE expression will throw an error because you are trying to return two values from the **CASE expression** which is not possible. You can at most return a **single value** from the expression, just like a **function**.

It could be written using **DECODE** in the **IN list**:

```
IN(  
DECODE(cur_ao, 'ALLA', Argus_ehandel_pkg.get_ehorder_ao (t1.nr), SUBSTR (cur_ao, 1, 2))), 
SUBSTR (cur_ao, 1, 2)
)
```

In the above **IN list**, there are two values, the **first** is evaluated by the **DECODE expression**, and the other is evaluated by `SUBSTR (cur_ao, 1, 2)`.

Comment: Very good explanation, the result I am trying to achieve is:

IF cur_ao = 'ALLA' THEN
   ao IN (Argus_ehandel_pkg.get_ehorder_ao (t1.nr))
ELSE
   ao IN (SUBSTR (cur_ao, 1, 2) , SUBSTR (cur_ao, 3, 2))
END IF;

Comment: @Crazy2crack Yes, it was a typo. Thanks, I corrected it.